# How to sort data by age with powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting

trying to sort a txt file in powershell by age when the data looks like this:

Smith,John,65
Walker,Luke,25
Mano,Jill, 88

trying to get it to look like this

Mano,Jill,88
Smith,John,65
Walker,Luke,25

Ive tries Format-Table but would just sort the names in order

any suggestions would be great

Comment: `import-csv file.txt -header last,first,age | sort age`

Comment: `gc file.txt | sort {[regex]::Match($_,'\d+')} `

Comment: Using import-csv file.txt -header last,first,age | sort age I get Last name Firstname 1....etc

Comment: And using gc file.txt | sort {[regex]::Match($_,'\d+')} Grouped the ages together

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```bash
# Simulate input from a file (e.g., Get-Content in.txt)
$fileLines = 
@'
Smith,John,65
Walker,Luke,25
Mano,Jill,88
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$fileLines | Sort-Object -Descending { [int] ($_ -split ',')[-1] }
```

This sorts by age *only*. You could add *additional* sort criteria in order to sort by name among those with the same age.

At that point, however, you're better off working with your data as CSV data, using [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) in order to parse the file into *objects* you can work with (the example uses the in-memory cmdlet version, [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv)):

```bash
# Simulate input from a file (e.g., Import-Csv in.csv)
$csvRows = @'
Smith,John,65
Walker,Luke,25
Mano,Jill,88
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header last, first, age

# Sort by age, then by name.
$csvRows | 
  Sort-Object -Descending { [int] $_.age }, last, first
```

Note:

- Since your data lacks a header (column names), it was supplied via a `-Header` argument.
- `Import-Csv` / `ConvertTo-Csv` parse CSV data into `[pscustomobject]` instances whose properties are named for the CSV columns and contain the field values.
- You can use [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) to export the results back to a CSV file, invariably *with* a header.

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, you'll invariably get *double-quoted* field values.
  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you can control the quoting behavior with the `-UseQuotes` and `QuoteField` parameters.
  - Use `-Encoding` as needed to control the output file's character encoding; notably, in Windows PowerShell ASCII(!) files are produce by default; in PowerShell (Core) 7+, BOM-less UTF-8 is the sensible default (which, unlike in Windows PowerShell, is the default across *all* cmdlets).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I was trying to figure this out and took a very wrong turn by trying to use the `-TemplateContent` parameters of `ConvertFrom-String` - that didn't go well!  Didn't realize `Sort-Object` could convert the string `age` to an int like that. Nice!

Comment: Ive also tried using the measure-object -Average to try and get the average age of them all is there a better practice to getting this output?

Comment: @Tiberious, replace the `Sort-Object` call with `Measure-Object { [int] $_.age } -Average | ForEach-Object Average`